# HDD not apearing in my computer

Tags: windows, windows-xp

I can see my extrnal HDD in bios and in device manager but it  doesn't apear in my computer, anyone with an idea?

Answer (score 1):

That's perfectly normal and doesn't indicate a problem. Hard drives *never* appear under `My Computer`. Only media devices and mounted filesystems (local or network) with assigned drive letters appear there.

Think of the chaos that would result if a hard drive appeared under `My Computer`. Say the drive had two filesystems on it. If you dragged a file there, which filesystem would it go on? If you double-clicked on it, which filesystem would open?

You can manage hard drives from `Disk Management`.

Comment: *Grins*. You just made my day. But I think we both know that @filipus was asking, even though he used the wrong names.